# What are the possible ways to access my account from guest session?

Tags: 14.04, sudo, su

My user account is recently damaged. Damaged in the sense, after I enter the password the same login screen is redirected again. So now I've to use the guest session.
**Are their any possible ways to login my user account from guest session?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would focus on fixing the problem with your account instead of using your "guest" account. Start by looking at `/home/$USER/.xsession-errors*`. Did you at an point use "root" or  "sudo" to access graphical elements? What does `ls -l .Xauthority` show?

Comment: @Rinzwind Sir,  first command displays : No Such File or directory 
Second command displays this : 
-rw------- 1 guest-3mXFOZ guest-3mXFOZ 52 फ़रवरी 14 18:43 .Xauthority
I'm recently using Guest session.

Comment: Can you select another Desktop Environment on the login page? Normally that's possible with the circle right top of the login.  If not change to a terminal with `Ctrl+F2`, can you login with your user account? If yes, do `sudo apt-get install awesome`, then `restart lightdm` and you should be able to pick a desktop environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 3):

You can not fix your user account from the guest account for a variety of reasons.

1. The guest account does not have sufficient privileges (no root access).
2. Even if you gave the account root access it is confined by apparmor.

You need to boot to recovery mode and identify the problem.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html

> The Ubuntu Guest Session feature provides a convenient way, with a
>   high level of security, to lend your computer to someone else.
>
> ...
>
> A guest cannot view the home folders of other users, and by default
>   any saved data or changed settings will be removed/reset at logout. It
>   means that each session starts with a fresh environment, unaffected by
>   what previous guests did.

I can not find the details of the guest apparmor profile on the Ubuntu wiki at the moment, but the guest session is too limited to help resolve your problem, whatever it may be.

I suggest you start a new question describing the problem.